# Scrolling Text in jMonkey

Tags: jmonkeyengine, text, quests

I am looking for a way to include scrolling text boxes in a jMonkey game.  I have, of course, looked around online and could not find any examples or libraries that fit.

My goal is to have "quests" pop up for the user in small graphical boxes, containing quest text.  The quest text might be longer than the quest box (which was easy enough to generate in jMonkey), so I am left with the problem of generating scrolling text boxes.

Before I set off on a long venture to properly adjust, indent, and scroll text inside boxes, I was wondering if any knew of existing examples or libraries. I have a hard time believing I'm the first person to using jMonkey that needed scrolling text or quest functionality.

Comment: What are you currently using to create the text boxes? Nifty is a GUI library that interfaces with JMonkey AFAIK. It has scrolling text boxes among many other built in features.

Comment: Ah!  It looks like Nifty has all I need and more. I'll have to decide whether it's worthwhile to bring all the functionality over, or just open up the base code to see if I want to replicate the functionality for this one feature I want.
Thanks so much! If you put your Nifty answer into an actual "answer", I will be happy to credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Nifty GUI library](http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/) is a pretty nice one. It [plays nice](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nifty-gui/index.php?title=Using_Nifty_with_JMonkeyEngine_2) with [JMonkey](http://www.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3aadvanced%3anifty_gui) (as well as others) and is fairly easy to use. Just this morning I set it up to reload the XML file with the click of a button. This allows me to rapidly prototype my GUI by modifying the XML and reloading without needing to restart my game. It also supports custom loaders, so you can ensure all your content gets loaded the way you want, or even support user generated mods to the UI. All-in-all, it's flexible and powerful.